# Vue i18n translate - How add ul/ol list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, translation

in my application I will have a large infobox with a lot of text. They will often be on a numbered list. I would like to find the easiest way for them so that I can easily send them from a developer to a copywriter.
Is there any smart way to create an HTML list (ul or ol) using vue i18n without breaking it into multiple variables in message. I would like to use e.g. [Component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage), but only call it once:  `<i18n path="info" tag="li">`. Quick code to show what I mean:

```
//translate.js (fragment)

   const messages = {
  en: {
    sample: 'Sample text with numbered list. 1) Find the problem 2) Ask on Slack 3) Solve the problem 4) Keep happy with vue'
  }
}

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', 
  messages
});

//App.vue (fragment)
  <ul>
    <i18n path="sample" tag="li">
    </i18n>
    </ul>
```

I would like the text in 'sample' to be divided by sub-points. I care about any way, it doesn't have to be Component interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in your localization as shown in the manual - https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/messages.html

Then you can build the template like this:

```html
    <ul>
    <i18n v-for="(item,index) in NumberedList" :key="index" :path="`sample[${index}]`" tag="li" />
    </ul>
```